# suricata in docker have Operation not permitted Error

Tags: docker, suricata

I built a docker image that has suricata in, but when i'm trying to run suricata, there is an error below:

> 3/9/2018 -- 02:58:12 -  - This is Suricata version 4.0.5 RELEASE
>   3/9/2018 -- 02:58:12 -  - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_SYSCALL(50)] - Failure when trying to set feature via ioctl for 'ens33': Operation not permitted (1)
>   3/9/2018 -- 02:58:12 -  - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_SYSCALL(50)] - Failure when trying to set feature via ioctl for 'ens33': Operation not permitted (1)
>   3/9/2018 -- 02:58:12 -  - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_SYSCALL(50)] - Failure when trying to set feature via ioctl for 'ens33': Operation not permitted (1)
>   3/9/2018 -- 02:58:12 -  - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_SYSCALL(50)] - Failure when trying to set feature via ioctl for 'ens33': Operation not permitted (1)
>   3/9/2018 -- 02:58:12 -  - all 2 packet processing threads, 4 management threads initialized, engine started.

docker images: ttbuge/suricata:4.5.2
run command: docker run -it --net=host -v $PWD/logs:/var/log/suricata ttbuge/suricata:4.5.2 suricata -i ens33

Any tips? thanks!

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it with `--privileged` option.

*For example*:

```
docker run --privileged -it --net=host -v $PWD/logs:/var/log/suricata ttbuge/suricata:4.5.2 suricata -i ens33
```